# Mock Generic Method with List of Objects

Tags: c#, unit-testing, moq

Below is my interface having 2 methods one accepting a single ICommand object and a second accepting a list of ICommand object.

My first method works properly but my second method is not getting called via Mock. But in the actual implementation it gets called.

Can someone suggest what am I missing?

```cs
public interface ICommandBus
{
    void Dispatch<TCommand>(TCommand command) where TCommand : ICommand;
    void Dispatch<TCommand>(IList<TCommand> commands) where TCommand : ICommand;
}

[Test]
public void Test_Should_Work()
{
    var commands = new List<ICommand>();
    var mockDispatcher = Container.Instance.RegisterMock<ICommandBus>();
    mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.Dispatch(It.IsAny<ICommand>())).Callback<ICommand>(x => commands.Add(x));
    mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.Dispatch(It.IsAny<IList<ICommand>>())).Throws(new Exception("Some Error"));

    var commandBus = SportsContainer.Resolve<ICommandBus>();

    var commandslist = new List<UpdateCommand>()
    {
        new UpdateCommand(),
        new UpdateCommand()
    };

    //first call is working 
    commandBus.Dispatch<UpdateCommand>(commandslist[0]);

    //its not working. expected should throw an exception. but nothing is happening. 
    commandBus.Dispatch<UpdateCommand>(commandslist);

}
```

Comment: What happens if you declare `commandslist` as `IList` rather than `List`?

Comment: How are you sure the first one works?

Comment: @NKosi first one i have verified the number of objects in "commands" list.

Comment: @MehulTalajia Ok this may be a co-contra variance issue. Trouble shooting here. Cast the invocation to what was setup in the expectation and see if that works

Comment: @MehulTalajia for clearer understanding you should also explain what the containers in the example do. Right now we have to assume what they do.

Comment: @Nkosi Container here is just an Unity (IoC) Container. and trying commandBus.Dispatch<UpdateScheduleCommand>((IList<UpdateScheduleCommand>)commandslist);  does not work.

Comment: @MehulTalajia No the setup expects `IList<ICommand>` so the invocation I was referring to `commandBus.Dispatch((IList<ICommand>)commandslist);`

Comment: @NKosi hey it worked thaks for directing . i just need to have multiple setup for it  mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.Dispatch(It.IsAny<IList<UpdateCommand>>())).Throws(new Exception("Some Error"));

Comment: or just declare `commandslist` as `IList<ICommand>`

Comment: @MehulTalajia Any luck trying my suggestion above?

Comment: @mjwills declaring commandslist as IList<UpdateCommand> did not worked. if it was IList<ICommand> then it would work but the method which i am calling is already having object List<UpdateCommand> so that was not in scope for me.

Answer (score 1):

Your test isn't testing any code from you, it's merely verifying that a loose mock works. You can't unittest an interface.

Your code doesn't throw, because you use a loose mock (the default) which doesn't do anything and just returns null for any non-setup call. You pass a `List<UpdateCommand>` to a call that's setup with `It.IsAny<IList<ICommand>>()`, which doesn't match, so your `.Throws()` is never executed but `null` is returned instead.

Don't mock the class under test, because then you're not testing anything at all.

So you want to test your implementation:

```
var dispatcher = new YourDispatcher():
dispatcher.Dispatch<UpdateCommand>(commandslist[0]);
dispatcher.Dispatch<UpdateCommand>(commandslist);
```

Comment: i am testing an service class which uses an object of ICommandBus so i am trying to mock command bus. and test real implementation. Here i have just generalized for better understand. If "It.IsAny<IList<ICommand>>()" is not correct. what it should be. ?

Comment: That the `It.IsAny()` doesn't match your call is the least of your worries. If you can get it to match (hint: `It.IsAny<List<UpdateCommand>>()`), then your code will do what you expect - but you still won't be testing your service class, **you're testing a mock**.

Comment: I tried It.IsAny<List<UpdateCommand>>() its throwing compilation error.

Answer (score -1):

I was finally able to get what i need. I need to be specific in defining setup for ICommand and it worked.

```
[Test]
public void Test_Should_Work()
{
        var commands = new List<ICommand>();
        var mockDispatcher = Container.Instance.RegisterMock<ICommandBus>();
        mockDispatcher.Setup(x => x.Dispatch(It.IsAny<IList<UpdateCommand>>())).Throws(new Exception("Some Error"));

        var commandBus = SportsContainer.Resolve<ICommandBus>();

        var commandslist = new List<UpdateScheduleCommand>()
        {
            new UpdateCommand(),
            new UpdateCommand()
        };

        //first call is working 
        //commandBus.Dispatch<UpdateScheduleCommand>(commandslist[0]);

        //its Working now.
        commandBus.Dispatch(commandslist);

}
```

Comment: This test is not testing anything except that a mocked call can in fact be called.